# Geometrical area relationship using vector cross product

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

[image]

In order to show the result, the textbook quotes that:

Area of parallelogram ABEF = Area of parallelogram ABCD + Area of CDEF + Area of BCF - Area of ADE

I cannot see why this relationship is true - it is quoted in a relatively straightforward manner, so I presume that I missing something?

Comment: With the two parallelograms on the right-side of equal you already made the area of ABCD. Then further you add and subtract the area of two congruent triangles-this part could have been missed unless is needed further in the proof.

Comment: @WindSoul Why do those parallelograms make the area of $ABEF$? I can't see geometrically why those two parallelograms have the same area in total as ABEF?

Comment: In terms of area, ABCD+CDEF=ABEF-ADE+BCF. The triangles are congruent.

Comment: Draw parallelograms $ABCD$ and $CDEF$ on a sheet of paper. Cut out triangle $BCF$ and translate it to the position of $ADE$. What do you get?

Comment: The relation given does not hold true for any choice of point $C$.  The sign of the cross product $ p \times q $ must the same as the sign of the cross product $ p \times r $.  This requires that the $ q $ and $ r$ vectors be on the same side of $p$ (i.e. in the same half plane).

Comment: @GloriousNathalie Yes, but you should say explicitly that your criterion holds when the vectors are all placed tail to tail.